# Circle CI docker cp file from instance to artifacts

Tags: docker, circleci

I am running CircleCI with Docker and then testing my code, after it is tested the test coverage percentage is recorded to a txt file which I want to copy to the artifacts folder.

```
- run:
      name: Run test coverage
      command: |
        docker-compose exec api mkdir /tmp_reports
        docker-compose exec api coverage report > /tmp_reports/coverage_output.txt
        docker cp api:/tmp_reports/coverage_output.txt /tmp/coverage_results
  - store_artifacts:
      path: /tmp/coverage_results
```

CircleCI Error

```
/bin/bash: line 1: /tmp_reports/coverage_output.txt: No such file or directory
Exited with code 1
```

I have ran this locally and copied the file from the docker container to my local directory, but circle ci seems to have issue with this. Can some one point me in the right direction here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the second line in your script, where you send output to the file `> /tmp_reports/coverage_output.txt`, that writes to a file outside the container. The redirect of output is handled by bash outside the container.

So on line 1 you create the directory inside the container, and line 2 it fails because the directory `/tmp_reports` does not exist outside the container.

You can fix this by replacing all 3 lines with:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/coverage_results
docker-compose exec api coverage report > /tmp/coverage_results/coverage_output.txt
```